# Exception java.security.InvalidKeyException: invalid key format while trying to load .openssl and .pkcs8 keys

Tags: java, encryption, openssl, apache-axis

While developing an axis client I need to encrypt String with publickey.openssl and decrypt with privatekey.pkcs8 loaded from local machine.thanks in advance.

running the code I get following exceptions;

```
      java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException:      java.security.InvalidKeyException: invalid key format
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyFactory.engineGeneratePublic(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.KeyFactory.generatePublic(Unknown Source)
    at client.client.readPublicKey(client.java:69)
    at client.client.main(client.java:97)
Caused by: java.security.InvalidKeyException: invalid key format
    at sun.security.x509.X509Key.decode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.x509.X509Key.decode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAPublicKeyImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyFactory.generatePublic(Unknown Source)
    ... 4 more
```

Code that I`m using:

```
public static byte[] readFileBytes(String filename) throws IOException
{
    Path path = Paths.get(filename);
    return Files.readAllBytes(path);        
}
  public static PublicKey readPublicKey(String filename) throws     IOException,NoSuchAlgorithmException,InvalidKeySpecException
{
    X509EncodedKeySpec publicSpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(readFileBytes(filename));
    KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");


    return keyFactory.generatePublic(publicSpec);
}
public static PrivateKey readPrivateKey(String filename) throws IOException,NoSuchAlgorithmException,InvalidKeySpecException
{
    PKCS8EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(readFileBytes(filename));
    KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    return keyFactory.generatePrivate(keySpec);
}
public static byte[] encrypt(PublicKey key,byte[] plaintext) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException,NoSuchPaddingException,InvalidKeySpecException,IllegalBlockSizeException,BadPaddingException, InvalidKeyException
{
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA1AndMGF1Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE,key);
    return cipher.doFinal(plaintext);
}
public static byte[] decrypt(PrivateKey key,byte[] ciphertext)throws NoSuchAlgorithmException,NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException
{
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA1AndMGF1Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE,key);
    return cipher.doFinal(ciphertext);

}
```

and giving the paths and encryption decryptions happens:

```
 PublicKey publicKey = readPublicKey("C:\\publickey.openssl");
        PrivateKey privateKey = readPrivateKey("C:\\privatekey.pkcs8");
        byte[] message = "11111111111111111|10:22:30".getBytes("UTF8");
        byte[] secret = encrypt(publicKey,message);
        byte[] recovered_message = decrypt(privateKey,secret);
        System.out.println(new String(recovered_message,"UTF8"));
```

Comment: Is your publickey DER (binary) or PEM (base64 text)? Probably PEM, since that's more common with openssl, but your Java code is loading *bytes*, so it should be DER.

Comment: thanks Andreas unfortunately webservice developer didn`t provide me DER nor PEM and I am stuck with these pkcs8 and openssl files.

Comment: If you open the `publickey.openssl` file in a text editor, what do you see? Is it binary or text? If text, does it look like this: [Sample PEM format x 509 cert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privacy-enhanced_Electronic_Mail#Sample_PEM_format_x_509_cert)? If it does, use openssl to convert from PEM to DER.

Comment: yes its the same ,thanks will try it and share the outcome